# How to use AJAX to call php page with parameter

Tags: php, ajax

I am using bit calculations so that I want to show the calculated value through php file so that I am trying to implement AJAX code but that URL not loading php file .., 
any suggestion please..?

```
function fun5()
{
    var id1=document.getElementById('city').value;
    $.ajax({
        url:'loaddata.php?id1='+id1,
        complete:function(data)
        {
            document.getElementById('show1').innerHTML=data.responseText;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the full url of that php file?

Comment: what should i add admin-ajax.php page..? how to customize it...?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work just fine, because there's nothing wrong with it, but...

### You use relative URL in it

You pass `loaddata.php?id1=` as URL. It's relative, so it will try to find loaddata.php file in current directory.

So if you're at the home page, then it will try to load that file from root directory. But if you're at some post (i.e. `example.com/my-post/`), it will try to load that file from `/my-post/` directory - and there is no such directory, so it won't end good.

You should use absolute urls to avoid this problem.

### You don't use admin-ajax

But... We're using WordPress, so... There is more wordpressy way of using AJAX.

All AJAX requests should use `admin-ajax.php` file and you should use `wp_ajax_{action}` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}` hooks to process such requests.

So your code should more like this:

```
function fun5() {
    var mydata = {
        action: 'loadmydata',
        id1: document.getElementById('city').value
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: LoadDataObject.ajax_url,
        data: mydata,
        complete: function(data) {
            document.getElementById('show1').innerHTML=data.responseText;
        }
    });
}
```

And in PHP file you should:

1. Define `LoadDataObject` object using `wp_localize_script`:

.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'loadmydata-script', plugins_url( '/js/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

// in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
wp_localize_script( 'loadmydata-script', 'LoadDataObject',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

2. Add your processing actions:

.

```
function loadmydata_callback() {
    // ... put your loading code here
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_loadmydata', 'loadmydata_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmydata', 'loadmydata_callback' );
```

You can read more on using AJAX in WP here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thanks for u r replay.., but i confused where should i add  point no:2 :-  2. Add your processing actions:

Comment: For example in `functions.php` file of your theme or in your plugin. There is a link to official tutorial at the end of my answer.

Comment: I added 1 & 2 point in loaddata.php file..., but it is not showing anything...?

Comment: @Darshan please read the answer. You shouldn't use any loaddata.php file at all, so adding anything to that file won't change anything...

Comment: i am strucking there if possible can u give me a step by step info please.., it is helpful for my life...

Comment: @Darshan I did. Have you even tried to look at the article I've linked in my answer? There is exactly what you're asking for - a step by step tutorial.